# Get unique fields for solr documents that have a certain value for a given field

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm retrieving a list of fields for all documents in my solr database. This is done in a straightforward way:

```
NamedList<Object> queryResult = solrServer.request(new LukeRequest());
```

However, my requirements slightly changed and now I need something similar but with one limitation. I want to restrict the fields only to fields of documents that have a given field set to a particular value:

Give me all unique fields for documents that have field 'foo' set to 'bar'.

Can I achieve this with a LukeRequest? If so, how? If now, is there another way to achieve this result?

Somebackground: I have a number of dynamic fields in my schema and import documents from various datasources. Each datasource has a field I actually know and which is unique for the datasource, but the dynamic fields differ for the data sources.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it using something like :

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery().setQuery("foo:bar");  
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(solrQuery);
```